# How to output multi language documents

Tags: languages, moderncv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whether it's possible to keep translation together with original text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/whether-its-possible-to-keep-translation-together-with-original-text)

I'm currently writing my CV using the moderncv package and I'm gonna need English and German versions of that. What is the best way to realize this without copy/pasting a lot of the code and so that changes I make to the layout will reflect both output versions?

Comment: Hi c089, welcome to tex.sx. I think your question is already answered by ["Whether it's possible to keep translation together with original text?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5076/2975). If it is, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If it isn't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: It sure does, thanks for helping me find it.