# How to not typeset LaTeX content? Or how to leave out LaTeX content?

Tags: environments

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
foo
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup
\label{baz}
\ref{baz}
\egroup
bar
\end{document}
```

Whenever you run LaTeX you get a warning like

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `baz' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
```

which is perfectly fine and expected. However, how would you leave out arbitrary (but sound) LaTeX content without printing warnings like that?

Why am I asking this or what do I want to achieve. I try to write a template for exams where I have an environment called `solution` and use it as follows:

```
\begin{solution}
  foo ...
\end{solution}
```

Whenever I toggle a boolean, the content inside the solution environment should be typeset or left out. I achieve the latter by saving everything inside a box as in the minimal example above. This works even if I have a `verbatim` environment inside my `solution` environment.

Comment: `\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup\let\ref\relax ... \egroup`

Comment: Many packages eg `comment` and some of the exam-specific ones define environments that can be switched in this way.

Comment: Related question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300189/tags-like-on-tex-se-but-with-the-ability-to-show-or-hide-both-the-tag-documen

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
\newif\ifsolution\solutiontrue
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!40!black}
\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{solution}{\begingroup\color{darkgreen}}{\endgroup}
%
%\solutionfalse % uncomment this to hide the solution
\ifsolution\relax\else\excludecomment{solution}\fi
```

...and it works quite well (I have not checked it with really tricky things, but an `lstlisting` seems to work).

(The seemingly overuse of another boolean is because I then use the `\ifsolution` construct in more macros).

#### UPDATE

As soon as I used it on my first non-english text, I found the problem explained in the question [comment.sty and UTF8 encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding) --- so the real solution, thanks to @egreg, is:

```
\newif\ifsolution\solutiontrue
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!40!black}
\usepackage{comment}
%% fix comment.sty for utf8 encoding https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159824/38080
\renewcommand\ThisComment[1]{%
\immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}%
}
\specialcomment{solution}{\begingroup\color{darkgreen}}{\endgroup}
%
%\solutionfalse % uncomment this to hide the solution
\ifsolution\relax\else\excludecomment{solution}\fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [*multiaudience*](http://ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience), [*optional*](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/optional?lang=en), or [*tagging*](http://ctan.org/pkg/tagging) packages.

There is also a really nice solution posted here using the etoolbox and verbatim packages, [*Turning parts of text on and off*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87656/turning-parts-of-text-on-and-off).

Comment: I think this would work better as an answer if it included one (or more) examples of how to use these packages. (Otherwise it is more of a [useful, to be sure] comment.)