# Book in two (or three) languages in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, languages

I am writing a book in two languages: a Russian version and an English version. Is it possible to do this in the same file?

Something like `\tltext{Hello world!}{Здравствуй, мир!}`, and mark at the start of the preamble which variant is needed.

The idea is that if I  needed to change something, I wouldn't have to do it in both files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whether it's possible to keep translation together with original text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/whether-its-possible-to-keep-translation-together-with-original-text)

Comment: This appears to be a near duplicate of the following question: [Whether it's possible to keep translation together with original text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5076/2693). If the answers there help you, we can close this question.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might just work, simply comment out the version that you don't want. You might eventually want to choose a shorter name than `\tltext` for the command because you're going to be typing it many, many times if you're writing a book.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tltext}[2]{#1}% use English version
%\newcommand{\tltext}[2]{#2}% use Russian version

\begin{document}
\tltext{Hello world!}{Здраствуй мир!}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

**babel** provides `\iflanguage`, but its usage for large parts of text is cumbersome.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\newif\ifenglish
\newcommand{\chooselanguage}[1]{%
  \selectlanguage{#1}%
  \iflanguage{english}{\englishtrue}{\englishfalse}}

\begin{document}
\chooselanguage{english}
%\chooselanguage{russian}

\ifenglish
  Hello world!
\else
  Здраствуй мир!
\fi

\ifenglish
  Thank you
\else
  Спасибо
\fi

\end{document}
```

In other words, you write each paragraph (or part of text in general) putting between `\ifenglish` and `\else` the English version, and between `\else` and `\fi` the Russian text.

You choose the language by commenting or uncommenting the lines after `\begin{document}`.