# How to create two PDFoutput from the same source

Tags: pdf, conditionals, source

I have a very long source file. I would like to prepare from this source two PDF files:

1. PDF contains all of the source file
2. PDF containing only a few, marked earlier parts of the source file.

How I should mark source file and how prepare main file in LateX, to achieve point 2?

Comment: Do you want to keep the same numbering for the second file as for the first? For instance, if in the second file you only have the figures 1, 5 and 10 do you want them to appear as 1, 5 and 10 or 1, 2 and 3 in the second file? Same question for the page numbers, tables, equations etc.

Comment: Ludowic C. : No, I dont want to keep the same numbering. I want to have own  numbering in the second.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have a look at [Producing different versions of a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22523) which should be what you want.

Comment: Crosslink: Special case of [compiling - Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files)

Answer (score 3):

In your long TeX input file (your source), use `\ifsecret ... \fi` to sandwich the secret parts that you want to either include or exclude. The common parts will always be included so don't sandwich them.

```
% filename.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\newif\ifsecret
\begin{document}
common 1

\ifsecret
I have a top secret message here.
\fi

common 2
\end{document}
```

Make a batch file as follows.

```
pdflatex -jobname=secret-included "\AtBeginDocument{\secrettrue} \input{filename}"
pdflatex -jobname=secret-excluded "\AtBeginDocument{\secretfalse} \input{filename}"
```

The following simulates your problem.

```
% compile with pdflatex -shell-escape

\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{filename.tex}
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\newif\ifsecret
\begin{document}
common 1

\ifsecret
I have a top secret message here.
\fi

common 2
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{pdflatex -jobname=secret-included "\AtBeginDocument{\secrettrue} \input{filename}"}}
\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{pdflatex -jobname=secret-excluded "\AtBeginDocument{\secretfalse} \input{filename}"}}
Done, secret-included.pdf and secret-excluded.pdf have been generated!

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{secret-included}}%
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{secret-excluded}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want include in 2 _only_ small part of source file. In your example: only text between \ifsecret .... \fi

Comment: @Ama: I cannot parse your sentences. Please use standardized English grammar.

Comment: @StiffJokes: I suppose @ama  wants a kind-of `only-secrets.pdf` document; a file with only the secrets.

Comment: @Romano - yes, I want `only-secrets.pdf` document. Can you help me?