# Multilingual text with if statement

Tags: conditionals, languages

I'm working on a document in LaTeX and I would like to have multiple language versions. I could just copy everything and translate, but this would lead to multiple versions that I would have to update individually every single time.

What I want is that I specify which language I want to compile (or perhaps it always compiles all the languages, so every time I run it saves for instance an english, dutch and german version). And then it only prints that language. I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
\languageversion{english} %this could be changed for language specification

\begin{document}
...
\dutch{some dutch text here}
\english{some english text here}
\german{some german text here}
```

So when I select english, only the english part would be printed. This way, if I would change the layout I don't have to do this for multiple versions, but only in one.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/is-it-possible-to-keep-my-translation-together-with-original-text)

Comment: This can work for very small snippets of text. For longer passages or an entire document maintenance would be very difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way, but I don't think this can really be useful for long texts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch,ngerman,english]{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\declarelanguage}{\@dblarg\@declarelanguage}
\def\@declarelanguage[#1]#2{%
  \long\@namedef{#2}{%
    \edef\@temp{\string#1}%
    \ifx\@temp\languagename
      \expandafter\@firstofone
    \else
      \expandafter\@gobble
   \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\declarelanguage{dutch}
\declarelanguage[ngerman]{german}
\declarelanguage{english}

\begin{document}

English

\dutch{some dutch text here}
\english{some english text here}
\german{some german text here}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

German

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\dutch{some dutch text here}
\english{some english text here}
\german{some german text here}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

Dutch

\selectlanguage{dutch}

\dutch{some dutch text here}
\english{some english text here}
\german{some german text here}

\end{document}
```

This will use the active language (according to `babel` rules). The `\declarelanguage` has an optional argument: a string that matches the `babel` language name. Using this it's immaterial what name you use; for example you could say

```
\declarelanguage[english]{EN}
```

and use `\EN{English text}` for inserting the English text. Take your pick; for German it's necessary.

Note: there's a strange `babel` feature: the language string maintained by `\languagename` has its first character of category code 12, that's the reason for the mysterious `\edef\@tempa{\string#1}`, which make your given string agree with `babel`'s opinion on the matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, you pointed me in the right direction! (I had searched before, without any results) Eventually I used the procedure from
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5286&start=0
Which is not perfect, but works for me!

Cheers!