# Why does this language test fail?

Tags: babel, languages

My problem is the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\def\suplang{english}
\ifx\languagename\suplang
    Supported language: \languagename
\else 
    Not supported language: \languagename
\fi
\end{document}
```

The result is "Not supported language: english" instead of "Supported language: english". What do I do wrong?

Comment: The implementation of `\languagename` has the effect that its replacement text is a string, that is, it is composed of category code characters. If you do `\edef\suplang{\string english}}` the test should succeed.

Comment: If it's string comparison you're after, you can also use `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\languagename}{\suplang}=0`, since the arguments to `\pdfstrcmp` are expanded for the comparison.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60112/multilingual-text-with-if-statement

Comment: You can use the `translations` package and `\ifcurrentlanguage{english}{true}{false}` or `\ifcurrentbaselanguage{english}{true}{false}`

Comment: See the manual, p. 8, which recommends `iflang` (see Heiko's answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For implementation reasons, the replacement text of `\languagename` has its first character of category code 12; as far as `\ifx` is concerned,

> `e`<sub>11</sub>`n`<sub>11</sub>`g`<sub>11</sub>`l`<sub>11</sub>`i`<sub>11</sub>`s`<sub>11</sub>`h`<sub>11</sub>

and

> `e`<sub>12</sub>`n`<sub>11</sub>`g`<sub>11</sub>`l`<sub>11</sub>`i`<sub>11</sub>`s`<sub>11</sub>`h`<sub>11</sub>

are *different*. Indeed, if you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\edef\suplang{\string english}
\ifx\languagename\suplang
    Supported language: \languagename
\else
    Not supported language: \languagename
\fi
\end{document}
```

then the output is

[image]

Do you need to do that business? No, of course not.

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % to work with all engines
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\supported}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\languagename}{#1}=\z@
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then

```
\supported{suplang}
  {Supported language: \languagename}
  {Not supported language: \languagename}
```

will work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % to work with all engines
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\supported}[3]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\languagename}{#1}=\z@
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\def\suplang{english}

\begin{document}

\supported{\suplang}
  {Supported language: \languagename}
  {Not supported language: \languagename}

\end{document}
```

Alternative definition with `\else` and `\fi` for the true and false branches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds} % to work with all engines
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\issupported}[1]{%
  TT\fi\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\languagename}{#1}=\z@
}
\makeatother

\def\suplang{english}

\begin{document}

\if\issupported\suplang
  Supported language: \languagename
\else
  Not supported language: \languagename
\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350080/16967) of egreg already explains the reason for the unexpected result of the example in the question and also shows several methods to solve the issue.

Package `iflang` wraps the internal stuff of the comparison with `\languagename` in a simple macro `\IfLanguageName`. The example of the question becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}
\begin{document}
\IfLanguageName{english}{%
    Supported language: \languagename
}{%
    Not supported language: \languagename
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]