# How to do \ifnot in latex?

Tags: macros

On the question [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/is-it-possible-to-keep-my-translation-together-with-original-text) one of its answers use a if then else:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifenglish
\englishtrue % Will show English text only
%\englishfalse % Will show Portuguese text only


\begin{document}
The technology.

\ifenglish
\else
    AAAAAAAAAAAAA
\fi

\end{document}
```

I would like to do `\ifnot` but throws the error:

```
D:\test2.tex:11: Undefined control sequence. [\ifnotenglish]
D:\test2.tex:12: Extra \else. [\else]
D:\test2.tex:14: Extra \fi. [\fi]
```

Comment: `\unless\ifenglish`

Comment: @Robert So ... `\def\ifnot{\unless}` ...?

Comment: @marsupilam better not call it `\if...`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good point ! I guess, that's why `\ifnot` is not defined, then !

Comment: if you want just the inverted tests you can of course do `\newif\ifnotenglish`  rather than `\newif\ifenglish`

Comment: What's the matter with keeping two files?

Comment: I would simply use \ifenglish\else ... \fi instead.