# How to override command on my preamble, after its redefinition by my class with renewcommand?

Tags: macros, lists, babel, abnt

I use this document class `abntex2` from: https://ctan.org/pkg/abntex2?lang=en, but when I generate this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}

\begin{document}

    \listoffigures*

\end{document}
```

The list of figures name is not overwritten by `Lista de Figuras`, it still `Lista de Ilustrações`:

[image]

It only works if I put `\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}` inside the document like this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de Figuras}
    \listoffigures*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why I cannot override it?

Looking at the `abntex2` code, I see they redefine the command:

1. https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/master/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2.cls#L163

```latex
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de ilustra\c{c}\~{o}es}
```

How to override the `\listfigurename` on my preamble, after the `abntex` class inclusion?

---

## Extra

If someone is wondering how I switch between English and Portuguese this is how:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newif\ifenglish\englishfalse

% \englishtrue
\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\ifenglish#1\else#2\fi}

\ifenglish
    \PassOptionsToPackage{language=english}{biblatex}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}
\else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{language=brazil}{biblatex}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{main=brazil,english,spanish,french}{babel}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{\lang{English Section}{Seção em Português}}

    \lang{Section contents.}{Conteúdo da seção.}

\end{document}
```

Which generates the following PDF in Portuguese:

[image]

If I uncomment the `\englishtrue`, then, the generated PDF document will be in English as follows:
[image]

Comment: Which language do you use, do you use babel?

Comment: Probably you want: `\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{My List}}`.

Comment: I use `english` and `portuguese` for babel with `\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\ifenglish#1\else#2\fi}`: [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076) - I added this `\addto\captionsbrazil` on my preamble and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}
```

is that it comes to late. At that moment `babel` was already loaded without that options you need. You need to move the following line above `\documentclass{abntex2}`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,english}{babel} % ,spanish,french <========
```

Please see that I deleted spanish and french not used in the mwe and I deletes `main=`. We change language later with command

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

To show that the code given below works with `biblatex` too I added an citing and printing of a small bibliography ...

With the complete MWE:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,english}{babel} % ,spanish,french <========
\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newif\ifenglish\englishfalse

%\englishtrue
\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\ifenglish#1\else#2\fi}

\ifenglish
  \usepackage[language=english]{biblatex}
  \selectlanguage{english} % <==========================================
\else
  \usepackage[language=brazil]{biblatex}
  \selectlanguage{brazil} % <===========================================
\fi
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

\listoffigures*

\section{\lang{English Section}{Seção em Português}}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{test}
  \label{fig:example-image-a}
\end{figure}


\lang{Section contents.}{Conteúdo da seção.}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{test b}
  \label{fig:example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\cite{knuth:ct,companion}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

gives us the result:

[image: text]

and bibliography

[image: bibliography]

If you want to change the usual used titles/names by babel please have a look to [this anwer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994/16550). It shows how you can for example change the brazil name for `\listfigurename`:

```
\addto\captionsbrazil{%
  \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de ilustra\c{c}\~{o}es}%
}
```